# Can pdo_sqlsrv driver be installed on Linux/Ubuntu with php 5.5.3 using pecl install pdo_sqlsrv?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, sql-server

In all likelihood, I have overlooked a fine print somewhere, so this question may sound stupid, but will clear my doubts.

I spent hours trying to install pdo_sqlsrv PDO driver on Ubuntu 13.04 PHP 5.5.3 server. The attempt was based upon a phpinfo() screen-shot sent to me showing such a driver available and enabled. So, I tried to get it working on a Ubuntu-PHP machine.

I saw pdo_sqlsrv and sqlsrv available when I check with

```
pecl search sqlsrv
```

Upon trying to install it (pecl install pdo_sqlsrv), I encountered phpize issue : "cannot find config.m4" (-this issue has a lot of coverage on web, but no clear solution).

However, it later dawned upon me what-if this module is for a Windows based setup and not for a Linux based PHP. Can somebody confirm that and point me to ideal setup for PHP with MSSQL driver enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for the sqlsrv extension at http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php

The SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows.

There is the experimental dblib
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fref.pdo-dblib.php&ei=dMkpU-qfEM3MqQG3voGIBw&usg=AFQjCNEDWwq6z9FlZUD4PqKRUXiOGQT6Pw&sig2=LsucfGyAAzq5uO6doPPXNw&bvm=bv.62922401,d.aWM

Comment: Thanks. Later that day I contacted the engineer who sent me a part of phpinfo() about his set that include the said extension (pd0_sqlsrv). He confessed that it is from a windows-apache-php server. I was ripping my hair apart!
I managed to get it working with freetds